# Unable to get value of form input in controller instead getting exception

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp, servlets

**DbConnection.java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class DbConnection {

    private Connection conn=null;
    private PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    private String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jsp_java?serverTimezone=UTC";  

    public void setConnection(){  
        try{   
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
            System.out.println("Connected to the database");  
        }catch(Exception e){  

        }   
    } 

    public void insertInto(nameBean nameb) {

        setConnection();

        try{
            String query = "INSERT INTO name_1(name)VALUES(?)"; 
            pstmt= conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, nameb.getName());
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }

}
```

**nameBean.java**

```
public class nameBean {

    String name;

    public nameBean(String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**ControllerServlet.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ControllerServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/")
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DbConnection dbconn = new DbConnection(); 

    public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String path= request.getServletPath();
        switch(path) {

        case "/insertPath":
            insertIntoFunction(request,response);
            break;
        default : System.out.println("error");  
        }
    }

    public void insertIntoFunction(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        System.out.println("name in field:" +name);
        nameBean nb = new nameBean(name);
        dbconn.insertInto(nb);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("homejsp.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override  
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
        processRequest(request, response);  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
        processRequest(request, response);  
    }  
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Image</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/insertPath" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**homepage.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>home page</title>
</head>
<body>
    HI, THIS IS HOME PAGE!
</body>
</html>
```

Here are my files that I am using.I am directing to controller after submitting the form but I am getting null pointer exception while retriving the value of name parameter and I am unable to understand why the error is coming.

Comment: `conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");` you did not put database name

Comment: I have taken database name in DbConnection.java in String url

Comment: Your problem is still reproducible when you remove all the JDBC/MySQL stuff. Next time try leaving it out form your question as per the rules in [mcve]. It makes nailing down the root cause easier for us (and you!).

Comment: okay, next time i will take care about that and thanks for letting me know.